# How to add a argument to jquery parallax

Tags: javascript, jquery, parallax

I am using the basic jquery parallax plugin: [parallax from Nike World](https://github.com/IanLunn/jQuery-Parallax)

The standard way to call the basic jquery parallax is $('.parallax').parallax("50%", speed, height).  I want to add one more argument 'img'.  So: $('.parallax').parallax("50%", speed, height, img)

I am setting the vars as follows:

```
$('.parallax').each(function(){
    var speed = $(this).data('speed');
    var height = $(this).data('height');
    var img = $this.data('img');

    $('.parallax').parallax("50%", speed, height, img);

});
```

This should be pretty straight forward.  Then in the parallax [gist](https://gist.github.com/Auxo/47887ab9b2f2538a89d0) you can see that I added the arg in the fn.parallax call.  Then I use it on line 63.  The issue is that the image won't show.  The background-position is the only rule output to the div.

Its poor mans debugging but I have console.log(img) all throughout the parallax.js and it shows the right image url.

What am I missing?

Comment: At line 63, you add `no-repeat` on the end of the `background-image` declaration, which I think is incorrect. Have you tried removing `no-repeat` and assigning that property separately (using `background-repeat`)?

Comment: if you want to supply the answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Per OP's request, here is my original suggestion in answer form:

At line 63, you add no-repeat on the end of the background-image declaration, which I think is incorrect. Have you tried removing no-repeat and assigning that property separately (using background-repeat)?